# Facebook Like Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Trying to get my facebook like button on my posts to show Post Title and Site Name - Right now it just shows the site url and post url (not post title) Any help would be much appreciated.

What I see now is - Ed likes http://www.wolverinesocceracademy.com/archives/8948 on wolverinesocceracademy.com.

What I want is - Ed likes Freshman Spotlight Q&A with Rachel on wolverinesocceracademy.com

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Might want to read the API documentation:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

You need to add specially crafted META tags to the head of your documents

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Frazell's Pizza Choices"/>
```

Comment: So add <meta property="og:title" content="Wolverine Soccer Academy"/>

Comment: Yes, along with any other attributes you want exposed to Facebook regarding that page.

Comment: Where would I add this in wordpress so I only need to add the code one time